# MySQL SUM multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sum

I have another question about sum.
I'd like to sum the scored of a baseball team, adding the scored when playing as local with the score when playing as visitor.

The matches table is like this:

```
Baseball_matches (Id, IdTeamHome, IdTeamAway, ScoreHome, ScoreAway, Status)
```

I'd like to group by Team, showing the total score for each team by adding the scored of matches that have the status os "played"

For each team: SUM ScoreHome when IdTeamHome + SUM ScoreAway when IdTeamAway

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Team,
       SUM(Score) AS Score,
       SUM(Won)   AS Won,
       SUM(Lost)  AS Lost
FROM   (SELECT IdTeamHome     AS Team,
               SUM(ScoreHome) AS Score,
               SUM(CASE
                     WHEN ScoreHome > ScoreAway THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END)       AS Won,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN ScoreHome < ScoreAway THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END)       AS Lost
        FROM   matches
        WHERE  Status = 'Played'
        GROUP  BY IdTeamHome
        UNION ALL
        SELECT IdTeamAway     AS Team,
               SUM(ScoreAway) AS Score,
               SUM(CASE
                     WHEN ScoreHome < ScoreAway THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END)       AS Won,
        SUM(CASE
              WHEN ScoreHome > ScoreAway THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END)       AS Lost
        FROM   matches
        WHERE  Status = 'Played'
        GROUP  BY IdTeamAway) D
GROUP  BY Team
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that's awesome !!! Also, I'd like to retrieve in the same query the number of matches a team has won and lost...is it possible?

Comment: Great!!! It looks very complicated. Is it going to work all right for a large table of matches? I'm very worried about temporary tables and all that stuff. Performance is very important for this project !!!

Comment: No idea. Can't see any obvious alternatives based on your table structure anyway.

Comment: Well I was trying to SELECT all teams and then making a SELECT SUM for every column I need from matches table...